# ¿Cómo hacer este borde con CSS?

Tags: html, css

¿Qué propiedades debo usar para lograr un borde cómo el siguiente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren. Ayúdanos a ayudarte. Qué has intentado?, Qué errores te aparecen?

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues un enlace desde dónde sacaste esas formas, así sería más fácil que te ayuden.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Si le hubieras puesto algo de código para demostrar por lo menos que has intentado solucionar tu problema, habría sido una buena pregunta. Las preguntas que no demuestren algo de trabajo y sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad (por lo menos por mi parte).

Answer (score 1):

para las esquinas redondeadas CSS BORDER RADIUS
para el fondo se me ocurre un contenedor 1 o 2 px. mas grande con fondo en LINEAR GRADIENT CSS
o bien

```
 border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,red, black ) 1 100%;
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Es genial que quieras ayudar y aportar tu conocimiento, pero las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad y la idea es no responder hasta que el OP edite su pregunta. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas como funciona la comunidad.